# Problemas com permissão

Tags: php, arquivo, fopen

Tenho um servidor onde estão hospedados 5 sites.
Um deles tem um sistema onde você baixa um arquivo que esta na hospedagem de um outro site, mas de um mesmo servidor.
O arquivo está lá, mas na hora de fazer o download aparece um erro.

Se eu troco pro caminho da hospedagem do próprio site ele consegue baixar o arquivo, mas quando é de outro lugar ele não baixa.

O código:

```
$patch = 'c:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\portalemme2.com.br\\web\\assets\\agencia_online\\pedidos\\'.$pedido->link_arquivo;

try{
    fopen($patch, 'r');
}  
catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Se eu troco o patch ele funciona.

```
Erro:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(c:\inetpub\vhosts\portalemme2.com.br\web\assets\agencia_online\pedidos\7654_Missa_Anglo_Indaiatuba.zip) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/matriculanglo2.com.br\;C:\Windows\Temp\)

Filename: controllers/Agencia_online.php

Line Number: 1739

Backtrace:

File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\matriculanglo2.com.br\web\application\controllers\Agencia_online.php
Line: 1739
Function: fopen

File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\matriculanglo2.com.br\web\index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(c:\inetpub\vhosts\portalemme2.com.br\web\assets\agencia_online\pedidos\7654_Missa_Anglo_Indaiatuba.zip): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

Filename: controllers/Agencia_online.php

Line Number: 1739

Backtrace:

File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\matriculanglo2.com.br\web\application\controllers\Agencia_online.php
Line: 1739
Function: fopen

File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\matriculanglo2.com.br\web\index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, 
verificando a mensagem de erro temos:

> Message: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect.

Pesquisando sobre open_basedir, cheguei a este link: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Trata-se de uma configuração do PHP que determina onde os arquivos podem ser lidos e escritos em tempo de execução.

Acredito que adicionando o diretório: `C:/inetpub/vhosts/portalemme2.com.br/` na configuração de open_basedir no php.ini irá resolver o seu problema.

Sugiro você configurar melhor o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento, pois ao que tudo indica este seu projeto tem este diretorio no open_basedir: `C:/Inetpub/vhosts/matriculanglo2.com.br/`

Comment: Eu coloquei "none" no open_basedir nas configurações do php e funcionou! obrigada